# What are all the possible results of moment.tzguess()?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

In moment.js, calling:

```
moment.tz.guess();
```

will return an IANA time zone identifier, such as America/Los_Angeles for the US Pacific time zone. It is documented [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).

And

```
moment.tz.names();
```

will return a list of IANA time zone identifiers.

**My question is**:

Does `moment.tz.names();` contain **all** the possible results of calling `moment.tzguess();`? I am attempting to get a list of all the possible results of `moment.tz(guess);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*moment.tz.names* returns all the IANA representative locations in the moment.tz data (there are nearly 600). The name provided by *guess* should be in the list, unless it was sourced from the Intl object and contains a name not in moment.tz's data.

You could also get a list of all IANA representative locations from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (noting that Wikipedia's list isn't authoritative, just convenient and includes current offsets for standard and daylight saving times).

```js
let repLoc = moment.tz.guess();
let allLoc = moment.tz.names();
console.log('Your IANA representative location: ' + repLoc);
console.log('In timezone data? : ' + allLoc.includes(repLoc));
console.log('All timezones:\n' + allLoc.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. I would upvote but new to SO and not enough rep.